Troubleshooting Tapswap task approval
I have tried doing the task on the tapswap dashboard,I connected my Solana wallet which was successful,I also joined Tapswap on X,I also visited the Tapswap website which was all successful,but then one task which is to join the Tapswap telegram chat is not approving even after showing that I have joined the chat,I have tried leaving and rejoining the telegram chat but it still tells me "go" instead of "check".
Please how can I rectify this?
